# Diferencia entre Html.BeginForm() y Html.BeginRouteForm()

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, razor

Básicamente esa es mi duda, que diferencia hay entre estos dos *html helpers*. y cuando se debería usar uno u otro.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La diferencia son los parámetros que toman

`Html.BeginForm` recibe los nombres de el *action* y el *controller*:

```
Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Home")
```

`Html.BeginRouteForm` recibe el nombre de una ruta, si es que le has puesto nombre a alguna:

```
Html.BeginRouteForm("MyRoute")
```

Acerca de cuando usar cada uno, si prefieres no seguir la convención de `/controller/action` puedes definir tu propia estructura para urls, en ese caso crearías tus propias rutas y les pondrías nombre para poder referenciar cada una fácilmente.

Comment: comprendo, entonces con `BeginRouteForm` le indico que routeo utilizar y `BeginForm` determina automáticamente que ruteo seguir?

Comment: Sí, `BeginForm` simplente depende de la ruta llamada "Default" creo